# CompletableFuture: can we log or know how many futures completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Let's assume we have a following code:

```
 List<Object> objects = ...
 CompletableFuture.allOf(objets.stream().map(d -> makeFuture(d, executorService))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
            .whenCompleteAsync((r, throwable) -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    // err
                }
                executorService.shutdown();
            }, executorService)
```

Where makeFuture is something like this:

```
private CompletableFuture<?> makeFuture(Object obj, ExecutorService executorService) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            // do the job
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // err
        }
    }, executorService);
}
```

So, my question is: can we know how much futures is completed every minute or log when every (for example) 100 futures completed?
I see an option to have a "global" Atomic variable an use it in makeFuture() method like:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomiInteger()
....
private CompletableFuture<?> makeFuture(Object obj, ExecutorService executorService) {
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        // job
        if (count.incrementAndGet()) % 100 = 0) {
            log.info("{} futures are completed", count.get())
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // err
    }
}, executorService);
```

}

But I don't like much this idea. In this case we have to syncronized actions. Of course, we cane make a local long variable and assign AtomicLong value to this variable and log it, but I am not sure about storage local variable in makeFuture method. There can be hundreds of thousands makeFuture() invocations. 
And for me, make a logging every N minutes is more preferable then log it every N futures completed.
Do someone knows any ideas?

Comment: Can you maybe share **why** you don't like that solution?

Comment: If you need to log after a time interval, then you have to use a different thread/schedule to do that; but you would still have to update a shared state every time a task ends, so something shall be synchronized.